# Show/Hide Text Entry Box on Single Choice MC Question

Tags: javascript, html, css, customization, qualtrics

I am new to coding and qualtrics in general. In sort of a time crunch but slowly teaching myself the basics of html currently.

I have a survey question that consist of a single choice MC question with three choices available. Each choice has a text entry box that appears for the choice selected. A hide/show function essentially. However, I am needing to add difference prefixes and suffixes for the text entry boxes like "$" and "annually". I am having an issue where the prefixes and suffixes appear before the choice is selected and the text entry box does not appear till you select the choice. Pictures below. The mobile picture at the very end also does not fit correctly. Any help is appreciated. I added my current code at the end.

EDIT: The mobile compatibility issue has been resolved. The hide/show issue has not been resolved yet.

The following images contain the question in this inquiry. The mobile view is also not compatible.

[Question before any selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nflRX.png):

[image]

[Question with selection and text entry box showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jMyX.png):

[image]

[Question with a different selection and text entry box show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Isyv.png):

[image]

[Mobile Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amc4x.png):

[image]

The code below is what I have currently:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{   
    
var textInputs = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" .InputText").css("float","none");
    textInputs.eq(0).before("$ ").after(" hourly");
    textInputs.eq(1).before("$ ").after(" annually");
    textInputs.eq(2).after(" %");
    
var QID= this.questionId;
    jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" input[type='text']").attr('type', 'tel');
    jQuery("#" + QID + " .InputText ").hide();
     jQuery("#" + QID + " input[type='radio']").each(function(){




            if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true)
            {  
                var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").show();
                }
           else
           {
            var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").val('');
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").hide();
         }      
     });




  jQuery("#" + QID + " .Selection ").on("click change",function(){


       jQuery("#" + QID + " input[type='radio']").each(function(){


            if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true)
            {
                    var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").show();
                }
           else
           {
            var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").val('');
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").hide();
         }      
     });
});
});


  jQuery("#" + QID + " .Selection ").on("click change",function(){


       jQuery("#" + QID + " input[type='radio']").each(function(){


            if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true)
            {
                    var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").show();
                }
           else
           {
            var v1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").val('');
            jQuery("[id*='"+v1+"~TEXT']").hide();
         }      
     });
});


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/


});


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/


});
```

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 480px){ #QID23 .InputText { width: 20% !important; } }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question? We're looking for the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added the html that corrected the mobile compatibility issue.            The only thing I need to accomplish is to have the prefixes hidden until that specific choice has been selected. Someone on qualtrics community mentioned placing the prefix items in a container (i.e. <div>) and then show/hide the container versus the input. I am not sure how to accomplish that. It is added to the question html view tab.

Comment: @DavidThomas Any update by chance :')?